# checking emptiness of the fetch array

Tags: php, sql

```
include("connect.php");

$SQL="SELECT * FROM promo ";
$run=mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");
$rec=mysql_fetch_array($run);
```

first,I want to check whether this query is giving empty records or not.
If it doesn't output any records , should print " no records in the table"
otherwise print all records using while loop. 
I can show the records using while loop. the hard thing is checking the output is empty or not.

please help me to do this. Thank you

```
echo "<table border='1' align='center' >";
    echo "<tr> <th> Room ID </th> <th> Start Date </th> <th> End Date </th> <th> Promo Rate </th>  </TR>";

    $run=mysql_query($SQL2,$con) or die ("SQL2 error");
    while($rec2=mysql_fetch_array($run))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rec2['roomid']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rec2['startdate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rec2['enddate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rec2['rate']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: so run an `if(empty())` in a while loop. N.B.: NULL != empty should you have NULL values. Or run a num_rows and check on that. Or count() many ways to do this.

Comment: If there're no rows `mysql_fetch_array` returns `false`.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: The manual for [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) **But heed the warning you see on this page**

Comment: ^ typo ^^^^^ ^ ^ ^^ ^^^ ^^^ ^^^^^^^^^ @RiggsFolly lol edit: Aawwww you fixed it.

Comment: I am all Tingers and Fumbs today @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can see that. Just don't go fumbling with the cod now. Slippery  fish huh?

Comment: Here, in which place do I need to add it , Please correct the code and post here.

Comment: seeing that edit of yours; yeah, I'd say I was right all along ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite you're using an obsolete API which is **deprecated** and in php7 even **removed**, the solution is to check number of rows returned by a query with [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php):

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM promo ";
$run = mysql_query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error");
if (0 < mysql_num_rows($run)) {
    while($rec2=mysql_fetch_array($run))
        // echo your rows
    }
} else {
    echo 'No rows found.';
}
```

But in the end - consider moving to more up-to-date APIs - [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it that way:

```
$i=0;
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($run)) {
   // print record
   ++$i;
}
if($i==0) {
   echo "no results";
}
```